Achieve the TPH using JMeter Tool
The Requirement is to Load Test the REST API'S.
1st Bussiness Flow(Test Case) with 50 Vusers and duration is 1hour.
1st Bussiness Flow(Test Case) contains 3API's.
1st API with 100TPH,
2nd API with 50TPH and
3rd API with 10TPH
How to achieve this in JMeter Please

If you want to run requests against 3 API endpoints with different throughput - you will need 3 different Thread Groups for this.

Put the requests as children of the Thread Groups
Add Constant Throughput Timers to limit the JMeter's throughput to the desired value for each API endpoint

